# validate route distance beetween two point (lat/lng or address) server side with google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

we are developing a web service (SOAP with php) that receives data from a client (browser):

- start point (lat/lng)
- end point (lat/lng)
- route distance beetween start point and end point;

the geocoding and route distance is calculated by google maps v3 client side.

by receiveing the data from the client the server must re-calculate the distance beetween start point and end point, to validate the distance itself, to be sure that it was not manipulated.

In terms of license, is it possible to do so using google maps v3 API? I've read that all API calls must be bounded to a maps display at some point, so I'm not sure if I can accomplish what I need without breaking some license terms.

We have a google maps v3 business account.

thank you

Alessandro

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of service, not coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, But note that the server-side Geo-coding service may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; Geo-coding results without displaying them on a Google map is prohibited by the [Google Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12).

If you are looking for geographical distance and not driving distance you can use:

```
function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true) {
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
    $lat1 *= $pi80;
    $lng1 *= $pi80;
    $lat2 *= $pi80;
    $lng2 *= $pi80;

    $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $km = $r * $c;

    return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);
}
```

You can also use : (passing lat & lon of two points)

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:77.23414,13.2323%20to:77.132,12.90925
```

This may violate the Google API terms 10.X.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I display a google map if I'm server side? will it be valid to pass the results to a client and display the map based on them?

Comment: Yeah, that would do I guess. Double check with latest Maps API terms once.